# During the deploy on vercel, I got error. I am building Next project

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth

```
WagmiProviderNotFoundError: `useConfig` must be used within `WagmiProvider`.
Docs: https://wagmi.sh/react/api/WagmiProvider.html
Version: wagmi@2.5.13
    at useConfig (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/wagmi/dist/esm/hooks/useConfig.js:10:15)
    at useAccount (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/wagmi/dist/esm/hooks/useAccount.js:8:20)
    at useConnectionStatus (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/dist/index.js:115:27)
    at ConnectButton (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/dist/index.js:5489:28)
    at Wc (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at Zc (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89) {
  details: undefined,
  docsPath: '/api/WagmiProvider',
  metaMessages: undefined,
  shortMessage: '`useConfig` must be used within `WagmiProvider`.'
}
Error occurred prerendering page "/dashboard/wallet_connect". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error
WagmiProviderNotFoundError: `useConfig` must be used within `WagmiProvider`.
Docs: https://wagmi.sh/react/api/WagmiProvider.html
Version: wagmi@2.5.13
    at useConfig (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/wagmi/dist/esm/hooks/useConfig.js:10:15)
    at useAccount (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/wagmi/dist/esm/hooks/useAccount.js:8:20)
    at useConnectionStatus (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/dist/index.js:115:27)
    at ConnectButton (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/@rainbow-me/rainbowkit/dist/index.js:5489:28)
    at Wc (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:68:44)
    at Zc (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:70:253)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)
    at $c (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:78:98)
    at Zc (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:71:145)
    at Z (/vercel/path0/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.production.min.js:76:89)

   Generating static pages (9/12) 

 ✓ Generating static pages (12/12) 
> Export encountered errors on following paths:
    /dashboard/wallet_connect
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

I made next login signup project and inserted connect wallet button.
And then I deployed on vercel, but there is an above error.
If you have any idea, it will be very thank you.

I think wagmi provider is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check the way your `pages` folder is composed. Managed to fix this by moving out the component from `pages` to `components` and that's it. This helped me a lot - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error